# Remove duplicate substring at the start of the string

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I would like to remomve duplicate substrings at the start of a string where a duplicate exists. I sort of have the logic working for the first row (see below) but am quite new to Python so am struggling to produce code which will apply the same logic for a rows in a larger dataset.

Below is an example of:

- Input: raw data i've created
- Output: what I'd like to end up with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Input' : ['john only played once john only played once yesterday. he may try again today', 'she didnt like eggs', np.nan, 'george found a dog lying in george found a dog lying in front of his car'],
    'Output' : ['john only played once yesterday. he may try again today', 'she didnt like eggs', '', 'george found a dog lying in front of his car'],
})

c = 20
df["Input_adj"] = df["Input"].str[0:c]

Input_1 = df["Input"][0]
Input_adj_1 = df["Input_adj"][0]
print(Input_1)
print(Input_adj_1)

Input_1_cut = Input_1.find(Input_adj_1, Input_1.find(Input_adj_1) + 1)
print(Input_1[Input_1_cut:])
```

I understand there are likely other ways of doing this and I'm by no means particular with the method used as long as output is as desired.

How would I go about transforming the input values into the output values using a simpler code?

Edit
One of the comments does solve this problem but it doesn't seem to work for the below input value (the actual text has no line breaks but I've included some below to better illustrate the duplicated text):

"Reed Brennan arrived at Easton Academy expecting to find an idyllic private school experience -- challenging classes, adorably preppy boys, and a chance to create a new life for herself. Instead, she discovered lies, deception, blackmail, and...murder. But, thankfully, the killers were caught and the nightmare is finally over.     Now, with a new school year ahead of her, Re

Reed Brennan arrived at Easton Academy expecting to find an idyllic private school experience -- challenging classes, adorably preppy boys, and a chance to create a new life for herself. Instead, she discovered lies, deception, blackmail, and...murder. But, thankfully, the killers were caught and the nightmare is finally over.     Now, with a new school year ahead of her, Re

ed steps back on Easton's ivy-covered campus ready to start over. So when the headmaster announces that billings is forbidden from holding their traditional, secretive initiation, Reed is relieved. She champions the new rules and the six new girls the administration has picked to live in Billings Hall: Constance, Missy, Lorna, Kiki, Astrid, and newcomer Sabine.     But Reed's fellow Billings resident and new nemesis, Cheyenne Martin, believes the changes are a mockery of Billings history. Despite the new rules, Cheyenne vows to keep the old ways alive, no matter what -- or   -- stands in her way..."

Does anyone know how to get it working for this example?

Comment: I think you got a typo in the 3rd example. Either way, with the current samples mabe just substitute [`^(.*)\1`](https://regex101.com/r/XHSCeZ/1) with the 1st capture group.

Comment: The last example seems to be incorrect. `'george found a dog lying on george found a dog lying in front of his car'` does not start with two repeated strings. If that's a mistake, use `df['Input'].str.replace(r'^(.*)\1', r'\1', regex=True)`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting out the typo (edited now).
Thanks @timgeb for providing a valid solution, would you know why it doesn't work for the extra example i provided?

Comment: @lsom107 does that string have linebreak?

Comment: @timgeb no it doesn't

Comment: @lsom107 again, this string does not start with two duplicated strings, so according to your specifications nothing should happen with it.

Comment: @timgeb perhaps it wasn't clear enought but I've added line breaks to better show the duplicated text within the example (noting the actual text has no linebreaks)

Comment: @lsom107 [works fine for me](https://pastebin.com/f2HdF7Nv) (also works when I put `s` into a dataframe and use my answer)

Comment: @timgeb thanks for that, i can also get it working when linebreaks have been added. Do you know why this doesn't work when the linebreaks aren't there because my input data has no linebreaks (as shown below)?
https://pastebin.com/7BJnrKd3

Comment: Seems like the issue isn't with the linebreaks but due to the fact that there is a space between the duplicate which is why the code hasn't picked up a duplicate. With that being said, adding a space at the start of the string enables the code to work as intended. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: @lsom107 those don't seem to be the same strings, the one without linebreaks only contains one instance of `', Re '`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` on the input column with a regex:

```
import re
df['Output'] = df['Input'].str.replace(r'^(.*)\1', r'\1', regex=True, flags=re.DOTALL)
```